# codename one android push notifications not registering for push

Tags: android, push-notification, push, codenameone

I am trying to get push notifications working with my cn1 app for android. I have it working perfectly on ios but for some reason for android it's not even registering. This is what I did

I started a new project in my play store console, input the app name and package name.

I then went into my google cloud console and generated a new api for my app and enabled GCM. This gave me a server key, project id (which was only 4 digits) and a project number.

I then try to register for push in my app using this code:

```
Hashtable meta = new Hashtable();
meta.put(com.codename1.push.Push.GOOGLE_PUSH_KEY, XXXX);
Display.getInstance().registerPush(meta, true);
```

For push key, I entered the 4 digit project id given to me in the cloud developer console. I then created a `KeyStore` for my app and sent it for build. However when I use the app it does not fire register for push and the device id is `null`. I have included the build hints `android.playService.*=true` only. I also tried to include both `android.includeGPLayServices` and `android.playService.*`, and it still didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is my project id supposed to be 4 digits. in examples online they appear to be longer than 4???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the developer guide section https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html#push-bureaucracy-android-section

You need the sender id:
[image]